# Bootstrap grid 3x3 Firefox vs Chrome bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following markup:

```css
.myclass {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.myclass img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootswatch/3.3.5/paper/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="main col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row myclass">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -3</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -2</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -1</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 0</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 1</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 2</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 3</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 4</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 5</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as you might see, it is 3x3 Bootstrap grid. But it behaves very stange: at my Firefox I have everything correct only with *.myclass*.
But without this line, I have 3 correct columns, than 2 clear columns and then 1 column in every row. With this line, I have bugs in Chrome: there are 2 correct columns and clear place instead of the third column. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you shouldn't overflow one row with columns of width sum larger than 12. That means each row you want to build in layout should be in separate `<div class="row"></div>`. Check if snippet below resolves your problem.

```css
.myclass img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootswatch/3.3.5/paper/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="main col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -3</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -2</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label -1</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 0</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 1</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 2</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 3</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 4</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center well">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <h4 class="for_bubles">My label 5</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but how should it behave in a small device case? Will they me arranged indepentently from rows? Can I get 2x4+1 at small device?

Comment: the markup crashes after width of 978px - I got two columns, that 1 column and the spot instead of 1 column. and the same is in every row....

Comment: It does not crash. You made it like this. Look how you defined columns: col-xs-12 means in extra-small window size column will take full width of row. col-sm-6 means in small size column will take half of width of row. You have 3 columns in one row, each half size of a row. You get the point?

Comment: yes, I do. But how to organize it in order to get 3 columns in a row for large devices, 2 columns in a row for medium devices and 1 coulmn in a row for small devices? Should I add .row after every column or I should have some conditional rows?

Comment: In order to do that you will need to get rid of row divs. I have updated my answer.